# how to use array as parameter in sqldatareader

Tags: asp.net, sql, ado.net, sqldatareader

I want to use array in sqldatareader object.

Code

```
for(int j=0;j<12;j++)   //12 use for month
 {
  if(j!=(mon-1))
   {
   ***String mont = MyReader1["('"+month[j]+"')"].ToString();***
   tt += mont;
   }
 }
```

I got error like

> **'January' System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'January'**

i use month name in array

and in database month name is colunm name

i have error in **MyReader1["('"+month[j]+"')"]**

Comment: Please show us table structure - columnname and datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If month is an array of string then try,

```
string month=MyReader1[month[j]];
```